# How to find the percentage of records that are over X in InfluxDB/Grafana?

Tags: grafana, influxdb

Okay, not the greatest title, but hopefully it covers enough. I will try to explain as best I can...

I have data going to InfluxDB that tracks how long that a specific action takes to respond and I want to add a Grafana chart that shows me the percent of actions that take over 1000ms but I'm struggling to figure that out.

InfluxDb Structure :

- **time** = the time the request was made
- **last** = the amount of time in ms the request took.

So for example, the following would chart the time each request took...

```
SELECT ("last") FROM "metrics"."autogen"."application_timer" WHERE time > :dashboardTime: AND time < :upperDashboardTime: FILL(null)
```

What I want though, is to track the percentage of requests that take over 1000ms. I'm extremely unfamiliar with Influx/Grafana so my pseudo code looks something like this...

```
select ((select count(last) > 1000) / (select count(last)) FROM "metrics"."autogen"."application_timer" WHERE time > :dashboardTime: AND time < :upperDashboardTime: FILL(null)
```

Could someone push me in the right direction with this? I'm sure its something simple, but I've read through a handful of tutorials on the internet and just can't seem to get my query right.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

InfluxQL is not SQL, so you can't do that with your current data structure. See InfluxDB doc - https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/guides/calculate_percentages/ where are also example data.